Which differential equations are invariant under change of camera projection?

For background, I am working in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I know that the derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are invariant under translation.
I know that the Laplacian $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}$ is invariant under rotations.

And now I want to consider homographies, which are invertible transformations $\tau:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $$\tau(x,y) = \left\langle \frac{ax + by +c}{gx + hy + i},\;\frac{dx + ey +f}{gx + hy + i}\right\rangle.$$
I have constructed one differential operator that I believe is invariant under all homographies: $$\mathscr{L}(F) =  F_{xx} F_y^2 - 2 F_{xy} F_x F_y + F_{yy} F_x^2$$
But I'm sufficiently unfamiliar with this area of mathematics that I don't know if there is a systematic way to find others, or all such operators. I also don't know if the answer to my question is a well-known result.
I'm looking for insights such as:

A characterization of these operators,
their closure properties,
a second example of a differential operator that's invariant under homography,
suggestions for how to efficiently establish invariance,
hints about how to generate such operators, and/or
keywords for what to look at next.

Most of what I've been able to find involves Lie groups on
manifolds, which is outside my area of expertise and feels
potentially heavy-handed and abstract for a situation in
$\mathbb{R}^2$.
Edit: Incidentally, I found this theorem, which states:

A differential operator $L=\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert\le m} a_\alpha(x)\partial^\alpha$ is invariant under all translations and rotations iff $L$ can be written as a polynomial $\mathsf{poly}(-\Delta)$ in the Laplacian $-\Delta$.

Because invariance under homography implies invariance under translation and rotation, I initially asssumed the theorem would apply here. After some initial confusion, I concluded that the operator in the theorem is assumed to be linear in a way that mine isn't, because mine depends on $F_y^2$ and so on. But I still hope the theorem represents a step in the right direction.

It has to be $g=h=0$ and then $\tau$ is an affine transformation? It is a special kind of automorphism of the real projective plane. It has automorphsim group $PGL_3(\mathbb{R})$?

Have you started with projective transformations of $\Bbb R$? Here you have the Schwarzian derivative. I have no idea how (or whether) it generalizes to projective transformations of $\Bbb R^2$.
